# The jar file is not reflecting any changes after making changes in code

Tags: java, executable-jar

I'm working on a java app. I created a jar file and after that I made some changes in my code about look and feel of app using Net-beans but the changes I made are not reflecting in the jar file. So do I have to delete the old jar file and then create a new one?

Comment: not aware how you built your jar, but did you ensure your project is compiled before packaging it in jar

Comment: Rebuild your project. Might need to do "Clean and Build"...

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-make you jar file again, the jar file is essentially a compressed file containing all the resources (classes, images, etc) required to run your program. So if any of your classes changed you need to recreate the jar file to ensure the updated classes are incorporated.

Comment: thank you Antony Ng.. for explaining the concept, I'll create a new Jar file.